# How to change iOS app name in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have multiple iOS applications for one organization. Whenever I create new app in Crashlytics and distribute to tester it is always showing the old app name instead of new app name. How do I change my iOS app name in Crashlytics?

Answer (score 7):

Mike from Crashlytics here.

Head to your dashboard at [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com) or [Fabric](https://fabric.io). Then click on the settings gear, select Apps, and then click on the app whose name you want to change. You do need to be an admin to change an application's name.

After that, hit the edit button to the left of your app's name below the icon and once you change the name, you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It helped me. The problem was I could not find edit button as am not an admin.